# ManyToManyField in Django with addinational information

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm trying to figure out how to add additional information with a `ManyToManyField` in Django. For example this code:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class Log(models.Model):
    animal = models.ManyToManyField(Animal)
```

If I would like to create a `Log` object and select the `Animal` object to it. Then I want to include more information in my `Log` like color of hair, colors of eyes with the `Animal` object there (I can't add those inside the `Animal` object itself).

And then I want to add another exactly the same object again to the **Log** object. For example a fox. So I want to add the Animal object twice for two different foxes to the log. The characteristics are the same but the only thing is some slight change in the hair color. How could this be accomplished?

Comment: I really wonder if you need an m2m field here. It means that an animal can have zero, one, or more logs, and that a log can have zero, one, or more animals.

Comment: You can specify through model in the django m2m field.

Answer (score 2):

django by default create a third model to handle manyTomany relationship, you can override this model and add your custom fields into it by useing **through**, as [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/) said use it like below code:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
   invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use m2m field, you can specify through model which will be between the models and can carry additional information, example here (https://gist.github.com/jacobian/827937). Some custom functionality can be done using signals that provides through model. It can be accessed with Log.animal.through.

But your design is i think bad. Better would be having foreign key with no reverse relation on Log and adding signal to post save which will on create created instance of Log and added information to it and set fk to the created instance of animal. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/#listening-to-signals